# How to find a shear force and bending moment on a slab,beam and column?

Tags: beam, column

I have no idea about shear force that how can i used it.also confused about bending moment when i try to  construct slab or beam

Comment: Would you mind to explain your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s complicated. Unlike wood joists and beams, concrete slabs and beams often are in “double bending”. That is to say, compression will be on the bottom and tension on top.

Determining EXACTLY where that occurs in a slab or beam is complicated and you’ll need an architect or structural engineer to help.